# Change the font, font color and background color of an NSTableView at runtime using NSFontPanel?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfontmanager

I'd like to enable the user to change the font of an view-based `NSTableView`. I'm using Cocoa bindings and Core Data. In my test code, I do have a `changeFont:` method that does get called as soon as I press a font-related key combination, like `cmd-I` or `cmd-B`, but I've had no luck so far in changing the actual font of the table view:

```
- (void)changeFont:(id)sender
{
    NSFont *oldFont = [self.airportTableView font];
    NSFont *newFont = [sender convertFont:oldFont];
    NSLog(@"sender: %@ oldfont: %@, newFont: %@ fontmanager selected: %@, font panel selected: %@",
             sender, oldFont, newFont, [sender selectedFont], [sender convertFont:[sender selectedFont]]);
    [self.airportTableView setFont:newFont];
}
```

produces the following output:

```
sender: <NSFontManager: 0x6080000b4580> oldfont: (null), newFont: (null) fontmanager selected: (null), font panel selected: (null)
```

Even this trivial code:

```
font = [NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
[self.airportTableView setFont:font];
NSFont *oldFont = [self.airportTableView font];
NSLog(@"oldfont: %@",oldFont);
```

only results in:

```
oldfont: (null)
```

Can any kind soul provide some code that allows the user to change the font of an NSTableView?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the font of the cell. Not the tableview. Use the following delegate method:

```
- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTextFieldCell *cell = [tableColumn dataCell];
    [cell setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:11]];
    [cell setTextColor: [NSColor lightGrayColor]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that the `NSTableView` is view-based. How'd I proceed?

Comment: @Mojo66 Then you need to set the font for individual labels in the custom cells in `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`

Comment: I got it working by using `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`. Any thoughts about which approach would be more suitable?

Answer (score 1):

Using the power of the internets, I was able to put together the following code fragment which responds to the `NSFontPanel` actions for changing font type, font color and background color of an `NSTableView`:

```
@interface AppDelegate
{
    NSFont                  *_font;
    NSColor                 *_fontColor;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] setTarget:self];
    _font      = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:0];
    _fontColor = [NSColor blackColor];
}


- (void)changeFont:(id)sender
{
    _font = [sender convertFont:_font];
    [self.airportTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)setColor:(NSColor *)col forAttribute:(NSString *)attr {
    if ([attr isEqualToString:@"NSDocumentBackgroundColor"]) {
        self.airportTableView.backgroundColor = col;
    } else if ([attr isEqualToString:@"NSColor"]) {
        _fontColor  = col;
        [self.airportTableView reloadData];
    }
}


- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    NSTableCellView *cellView   = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:[tableColumn identifier] owner:self];
    NSTextField *textField      = [cellView textField];
    textField.font          = _font;
    textField.textColor     = _fontColor;
    return cellView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    return _font.boundingRectForFont.size.height + 2.0f;
}
```

Note the explicit calls to `reloadData`, otherwise the visible part of the table view won't update. Let me know if there are better solutions.

Also note that `-setColor:forAttribute:` is undocumented. Apparently, if your class responds to it, `-changeAttributes:` will not get called.